# Variable key on php enum

Tags: php, enums, php-8.1

Is it possible to access enumerations properties dynamically?

Here is what I tried and the error I got.

> Access to undeclared static property ExampleEnum::$id

```php
enum ExampleEnum
{
    case _1;
    case _2;

    public function getIt(): string
    {
        return match ($this) {
            ExampleEnum::_1 => 'foo',
            ExampleEnum::_2 => 'bar',
        };
    }
}

$id = "_1";
ExampleEnum::$id->getIt();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's important to distinguish between three different things here:

- A class *property* would be declared in a class as `static $foo` (with optional visibility, type, and default value), and accessed as `Example::$foo`. Dynamically, you could access that with "variable-variable" syntax, e.g. `$name = 'foo'; echo Example::$$name;`.
- A class *constant* would be declared as `const foo = 'value'` (with optional visibility), and accessed as `Example::foo`. From PHP 8.3 onwards, you could access that dynamically with `$name = 'foo'; echo Example::{$name};`. In earlier versions, there was no direct syntax, but you could use [the `constant` function](https://php.net/constant), as in `$name = 'foo'; echo constant("Example::$name");`
- An *enum case* is declared as `case foo` (with a value if using a "backed enum"), and it is accessed using the same syntax as a class constant.

In fact, an enum case is treated like a constant in many ways, and a test shows that both the `constant` function and the PHP 8.3 dynamic constant syntax can be used to look one up, so this will work:

```
enum ExampleEnum
{
    case _1;
    case _2;

    public function getIt(): string
    {
        return match ($this) {
            ExampleEnum::_1 => 'foo',
            ExampleEnum::_2 => 'bar',
        };
    }
}

$id = "_1";

// PHP 8.3 or later only:
echo ExampleEnum::{$id}->getIt();

// any version supporting enums (PHP 8.0 or later):
echo constant("ExampleEnum::$id")->getIt();
```

Note that if you use a ["backed enumeration"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php), you can associate an arbitrary integer or string with each case, separate from its name, and use the `from` method to look up a case based on that value.

Comment: This helped me out, and indeed works as described. Thank you!